# savehist-mode: Lisp error: (void-variable pell-buffer)

Tags: debugging, variables

I am using `GNU Emacs 26.3` in `macOS`. For `(savehist-mode 1)` I keep getting following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable pell-buffer)
  signal(void-variable (pell-buffer))
  savehist-mode(1)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/alper/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 98709
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/alper/.emacs" "/Users/alper/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x400d1a6d>)()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

What may be the main cause of this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Load the library/code that defines variable `pell-buffer`. `require` it, autoload it, or do something else that ensures that it's loaded before you invoke the code that raises the error.

Comment: This is no doubt a duplicate, but I don't have time to search for it now. Please search for that error message, and if you find a duplicate question the please delete this one. Thx.

Comment: I couldn't find which library covers `pell-buffer`

Comment: Is it a value in ~/.emacs.d/history? You may of had a package installed that had the variable which you have since removed.

Comment: Yes there is a line as `pell-buffer" "customize-face"))` but I am not sure it may make `ispell-buffer` accidently as `pell-buffer`

Comment: Bisect your init file to find which part causes the problem.

Comment: ah there is no line exists as `pell-buffer`